# how to add item condition "new/used' on product page

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm using magento 1.9.3.8 and looking to add a costume filed on the product page, which will be next to the availability filed on the front end.

Comment: You can create an attribute and while making new products you can mark them in backend and on frontend product page you can call them

Comment: Thanks @inrsaurabh how I can show it next to the price if you can help me with that please.

Comment: Ok, though it's very easy to do so and if you search will surely find many solutions and article on the same, i will post an answer in some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a custom attribute from the backend

1) catalog -> attributes -> add new attribute

Fill all the required details lets say you want a `yes/no` type

[image: defaultValues]

Then assign this newly created attribute to the attribute sets that you are using ( maybe default one )

Go to
2) catalog -> attributes -> Manage Attribute Sets and click select the attribute set and drag the newly created attributes to that group and click save

3) Open any product that using that attribute group and you will find a new section with the label 
[image: yes/No]

Now call them on the product page

Go to current active theme like this one 
**/var/www/html/magento19/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml**

and use this code

```
if($_product->getProductStatus()) { ?>
        <div class="productStatus">
            <span>Product Status :</span> <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('product_status'); ?>
        </div>
     <?php } ?>
```

**NOTE :**  we use `Attribute Code` value after get ( getProductStatus() )

Hope it helps you.